# Error when Uploading image in ASP.NET MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On the local machine the code below works fine, but when hosted on remote server it doesn't seem to find the image file. I created the Image folder and gave it read/ write permissions as well

// --------------------------------------------
Error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.  
Could not find file 'IdImage.jpg'.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

`Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'IdImage.jpg'.`

Code is as below
// ---------------------------------------------

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)  
{  
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)   
    {  
       var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
       var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Photo"), fileName);  
       file.SaveAs(path);  
    }  

    return RedirectToAction("Index");          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like a permission problem. You said that you have created the `Images` folder and gave it read/write permission, but from what I can see in your code you are attempting to store the image inside a subfolder called `Photo`. So make sure you have created this folder as well and given read/write permissions to it as well. Also make sure that you are giving those permissions to the correct account - the one that's configured in IIS to run the application pool in which your application is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
       string filename = Server.MapPath("~/files/somename");
       file.SaveAs(filename);
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

in view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
}
<h2>
    Upload</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Upload", controllerName: "User", 
                       method: FormMethod.Post,
                       htmlAttributes: new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <text>Upload a photo:</text> <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```